# How to increment a column value by one in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in which I want to update the years for every row. I just want the year to go up by one in each row.

```
UPDATE myTable
SET YEAR = YEAR + 1
```

When I run the above code, I get a "String '2021.0000000' is too long and would be truncated" error. I put the YEAR Field as VARCHAR(4) in my data storage type. So I'm not sure why there's an error.

Comment: *"I put the YEAR Field as VARCHAR(4) in my data storage type."* - Sounds like it should have been a numeric data type, especially if you want to perform math on it.  Your best bet is probably to fix the data type first.

Answer (score 2):

A VARCHAR is a string.  A string can't have 1 added to it.  A numeric type could.  You can convert and then add one and convert it back like this:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET YEAR = CAST((CAST(YEAR AS INTEGER)+1) AS VARCHAR(4))
```

However, I think this makes it clear that you used the wrong data type for year -- a year is a number, not a string.

Comment: you should mention that is is a costly operation

Comment: @nbk -- I could probably write a book about all the things wrong and bothersome about it -- instead I just said it is the wrong type and went on with my life.  Thus not making it a costly operation for me :)

Comment: even so most get their interest pricked when they hear that their approach will cost lots of time, so i believe it  lasts longer in memory

Comment: @nbk -- this will be slower to do the cast -- in the scope of relational databases what matters is how many rows are being updated.  If it is less than 1k or so then this won't be a big deal.  If it is 10m then the double cast might have an impact on system performance.  (Depending on system load.)  It is all relative.

Comment: @Hogan I appreciate the solution. Is there a less costly way to do this? My table has around 15K rows. Maybe if I create a temporary table so I don't have to use the cast function if it gets too costly. 

Thank you.

Comment: one alter Table will not be slower and will help performance for the future

Comment: @ShabMeh: The less costly approach is to correct the data type.  Then you don't have to worry about which workaround for using the wrong data type is better or worse than another workaround.

Comment: @David this is an existing table that I don't want to mess around with. Can I create a temporary table to correct the data type?

Comment: The only way to make this work correctly @ShabMeh is to use the correct design, which is the correct data type.   Can I ask why you are reluctant to store the year as an integer?  If you don't have a reason then the BEST thing to do is change it.

Comment: @ShabMeh: Sure, if you want.  At this point your question is becoming, "I don't want to solve the problem, I just want a hack workaround."  In that case use whatever hack workaround you like.  Try different things and see what "works" for your needs.  All while not solving the actual problem.  (Edit: If solving the problem is outside your control, such as a boss who requires that the wrong data type continue to be used, then that boss is encouraged to also suggest workarounds for their invented problem.)

Answer (score 1):

Other commenters are correct - change the datatype.
Although in MySQL changing column type is a blocking operation, you can play around that with pt-online-schema-change tool or you can try the good ol' trick with adding a new NULLable column, updating it's values from old column and then renaming the columns.
But if you really want to make BAD software, you can use cast as suggested or, even worse you can read about SQL_MODE in mysql, especially about STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, it can turn your error into warning. But this is a straight path to the world of pain since your data may be truncated silently.
And do always specify your MySQL version and flavour, since they have differences.

Comment: Why the MySql assumption? "String ... is too long and would be truncated" is a Snowflake error message

Comment: @MartinSmith idk, i faced similar sounding errors in MySQL. It just popped up in my mind like it is the only option :-)